# What does code Parameter in UriMatcher constructor mean?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

code parameter in UriMatcher(int code) constructor according to [Android Developer Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/UriMatcher.html) used to "match for the root URI" and code usually NO_MATCH
which has value equal to -1

this answer is not clear for me why put this value and the uri in getType methode match against uri in addUri methode ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integer code you provide to the constructor for `UriMatcher` is returned by `match()` when it is called with a `Uri` that contains neither an authority nor a path.

This demonstrates the behavior:

```
        UriMatcher m = new UriMatcher(999);

        m.addURI("com.example", "pathsegment", 11);

        //found; code= 11
        Log.i("Test", String.format("Match code= %d", m.match(Uri.parse("content://com.example/pathsegment"))));
        //not found; code= -1
        Log.i("Test", String.format("Match code= %d", m.match(Uri.parse("content://com.example/xxxxxx"))));
        //root; code= 999
        Log.i("Test", String.format("Match code= %d", m.match(Uri.parse("content:"))));
        //root; code= 999
        Log.i("Test", String.format("Match code= %d", m.match(Uri.parse(""))));
```